# Interactive Shell with Mina and Capistrano

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, capistrano3, mina

Capistrano Doc says

http://capistranorb.com/documentation/faq/why-does-something-work-in-my-ssh-session-but-not-in-capistrano/#

```
ssh me@remote "[[ $- == *i* ]] && echo 'Interactive' || echo 'Not interactive'"
Interactive
me@localhost $ ssh me@remote "shopt -q login_shell && echo 'Login shell' || echo 'Not login shell'"
Not login shell
```

Capistrano state that the command runs on ssh me@remote in "**Interactive and Non login shell**". Very well but here is my point.

What I did is, I added a simple test in my **.bashrc** that look like this

```
echo $-
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
   *i*) echo 'Interactive';;
     *) echo 'Non Interactive';;
esac
```

Now, Instead of double quote (`"`) I wrapped the Capistrano example in a single quote (`'`) because I felt the double quote **expand the expression for the current shell** (in my case it's my laptop `tty` terminal)

Result :

```
ssh me@remote '[[ $- == *i* ]] && echo "Interactive" || echo "Not interactive"'
hBc
Non Interactive
Not interactive
```

`Question 1:` - Is the Capistrano doc **correct?**. Looking my result above it seems that command runs via ssh run in **non-interactive and non-login** shell.

`Question 2:` 
If I'm correct(in term of Question 1) how can I run a command in an interactive shell?. I was under the impression `-t` options would force `tty` allocation and that would help. But that doesn't help either.

```
ssh me@remote -t '[[ $- == *i* ]] && echo "Interactive" || echo "Not interactive"'
hBc
Non Interactive
Not interactive
Connection to remote closed.
```

`Question 3:` To the Original question now. I'm using Mina for my deployment stuff.Now, during mina deploy the rvm never loads.

Reason my bash has the following definitions in **bashrc**

```
# bashrc
case $- in #when mina load bashrc it's a non-interactive shell.
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm  # this is never gets executed
```

`Question 4(a)` 
How do people work around this problem?. Surely moving the rvm source load at the top of the file help but I looking for a different answer.

`Question 4 b` :  How does Capistrano and Mina handle it. If they can?

Comment: It looks like the linked docs are correct: "By default Capistrano always assigns a non-login, non-interactive shell."

Answer (score 2):

I don't use RVM, but I'll take a quick crack at your question:

Q1: Unless there is another piece of the documentation that I'm missing, you've mis-quoted. It says:

> By default Capistrano always assigns a non-login, non-interactive shell.

Q2: You can't/shouldn't. Capistrano deploys *should* be fully unattended, in which case there is no need for an interactive shell.

Q3: This is where I'm not sure, because I've only used rbenv. However I'll give it a shot. Use https://github.com/capistrano/rvm to set up RVM. Once you have that, if you have a command in addition to those listed here: https://github.com/capistrano/rvm/blob/master/lib/capistrano/tasks/rvm.rake#L53, use `append :rvm_map_bins, 'nameofexecutable'` to make RVM apply to your command.

Q4a/b: See Q3.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me but I was referring to this part [http://capistranorb.com/documentation/faq/why-does-something-work-in-my-ssh-session-but-not-in-capistrano/#how-can-i-check](http://capistranorb.com/documentation/faq/why-does-something-work-in-my-ssh-session-but-not-in-capistrano/#how-can-i-check)